# What happens if you index a map in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in mongodb which contains a map like this:

```
{
     "name": "Document 1",
     "attrinutes": {
           "key1": "value1",
           "key2": "value2",
           "key3": "value3"
     }
}
```

If I create an index on attributes like this:

```
db.ensureIndex ({"attributes":-1})
```

What would the index look like and what type of query would use this index?

Comment: Update to make the question more specific.  The question you mentioned does not address what I am asking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setup you mentioned will index "attributes" as a blob, and will not be used for any queries that need to inspect values within the actual attributes document.  If you want to be able to do the equivalent of a query like

```
{ "attributes.key1" : "value1" }
```

and have it use an index, then you could structure the document

```
{
    "name" : "Document1",
    "attributes" [
        { "key" : "key1", "value", "value1" },
        { "key" : "key2", "value", "value2" }
    ]
}
```

Then, depending on what you need to do, either index "attributes" itself, or create a compound index on "attributes.key" and "attributes.value".

Answer (score 1):

It's still the same basic question as the duplicate.  An index on `attributes` would be done as a binary blob so it could only be used for queries like:

```js
db.coll.find({attributes: {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value3'}})
```

So it can't be used for a query on the individual keys of `attributes`, only the object as a whole.

Comment: Thanks, after reading the other question again, it makes sense.  Basically i need to store a list of key-value pair instead of a map if i want the index to work properly. I will close the question